# Testing a method with JUnit and Mockito to enhance branch coverage

Tags: java, junit, mockito, cobertura

I am writing a `JUnit` to enhance the line and branch coverage of a method. There is only one line left in method under test that I am trying to cover but somehow it is not being covered. I've tried to use `Mockito` to make it simpler but still `if( o != null )` comes as red in `Cobertura` Report.

Method under test:

```
public String handleParams( Map<String, Object> params ) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if( params != null ) {
        Set<String> keys = params.keySet();
        for( String s : keys ) {
            Object o = params.get( s );
            if( o != null ) {
                if( sb.length() > 0 ) {
                    sb.append("," );
                }
                sb.append( s + "-" + o.toString() );
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testHandleParams() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Object1", new Object());
    params.put("Object2", new Object());

    TestWSAuditHandler handler = new TestWSAuditHandler();
    String handle = handler.handleParams(params);

    assertNotNull(params);
    assertEquals(2, params.size());
    assertTrue(handle instanceof String);

    // Null Condition
    params = null;

    handler = new TestWSAuditHandler();
    handle = handler.handleParams(params);

    assertNull(params);
    assertEquals(null, params);
    assertTrue(handle instanceof String);

    // Mocking params
    params = Mockito.mock(Map.class);
    Mockito.when(params.get(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);

    handler = new TestWSAuditHandler();
    handle = handler.handleParams(params);
}
```

Want to know how will I make `o` == null

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
params.put("Object3", null);
```

before your call to `handleParams`?

This way, when you will call `params.get("Object3")` in `handleParams`, you will get the value associated to the key `Object3`, which in this case is `null`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide more explanation - is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you Chris.